Loop is not working with data type test as conditional in Ansible
When I execute ansible playbook with this command and extra vars as
ansible-playbook controller_config/windows_domain_names.yml -e "target_win_host=testserver.testdomain.com"

with one task inside it
- name: Find if the variable target_win_host is a list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }} is list data type"
  loop: "{{ target_win_host}}"
  when: target_win_host | type_debug == 'list'

I got the error as

"Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: testserver.testdomain.com. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."

I expect the above block should be skipped as this does not meet the condition that variable is a list and that its a scalar (string).
I tried with different condition as below
- name: Find if the variable target_win_host is a list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }} is list data type"
  loop: "{{ target_win_host}}"
  when: target_win_host is not string and target_win_host is iterable and target_win_host is sequence

but same error as above.

You approach won't work because for the given task, the loop expression is first evaluated, the first item is extracted and only then the when: condition is evaluated (once for each loop iteration).
In other words, for your approach to work, you need to somehow embed the condition in the loop: expression and make it result to a zero length list.
The following task achieves that goal:
- name: Loop over target_win_host if it is a list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }} is part of a list of hosts"
  loop: "{{ target_win_host if target_win_host | type_debug == 'list' else [] }}"

Meanwhile if you'd rather play the same task for all hosts whether they are given as a list or as a single host string, this is probably better:
- name: Loop over hosts in target_win_host whether it is a list or a single host string
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }} was given as one the hosts"
  loop: "{{ [target_win_host] | flatten }}"

This is a full playbook to test both options:
---
- name: Conditional and loops
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # default value as a list. Override with extra vars
    target_win_host:
      - host1.example.com
      - host2.example.com

  tasks:
    - name: Loop over target_win_host if it is a list
      debug:
          msg: "{{ item }} is part of a list of hosts"
      loop: "{{ target_win_host if target_win_host | type_debug == 'list' else [] }}"


    - name: Loop over hosts in target_win_host whether it is a list or a single host string
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} was given as one of the hosts"
      loop: "{{ [target_win_host] | flatten }}"

Which gives:
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [Conditional and loops] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Loop over target_win_host if it is a list] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=host1.example.com) => {
    "msg": "host1.example.com is part of a list of hosts"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=host2.example.com) => {
    "msg": "host2.example.com is part of a list of hosts"
}

TASK [Loop over hosts in target_win_host whether it is a list or a single host string] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=host1.example.com) => {
    "msg": "host1.example.com was given as one of the hosts"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=host2.example.com) => {
    "msg": "host2.example.com was given as one of the hosts"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ ansible-playbook test.yml -e target_win_host=a.single.host

PLAY [Conditional and loops] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Loop over target_win_host if it is a list] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Loop over hosts in target_win_host whether it is a list or a single host string] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=a.single.host) => {
    "msg": "a.single.host was given as one of the hosts"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0


Create a switch. For example,
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ switch }}"
      vars:
        target: "{{ target_hosts | d([]) }}"
        type: "{{ target | type_debug }}"
        switch: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% if type == 'str' %}
          {{ target | split(',') }}
          {% elif type == 'list' %}
          {{ target }}
          {% elif type == 'dict' %}
          {{ target.keys() }}
          {% else %}
          []
          {% endif %}
          {% endfilter %}


When target_hosts is not defined the loop skips the default empty list

  target: "{{ target_hosts | d([]) }}"


When target_hosts is a single string

shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e target_hosts=host1

gives
  msg: host1


The comma-separated string also works as expected

shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e target_hosts=host1,host2

gives
  msg: host1
  msg: host2


You can provide a list as an extra variable. Put it into a file. For example,

shell> cat target_hosts_list.yml
target_hosts:
  - host1
  - host2

The list also works as expected
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e @target_hosts_list.yml

gives the same result
  msg: host1
  msg: host2


You can even provide a dictionary if you want to

shell> cat target_hosts_dict.yml
target_hosts:
  host1: whatever you want 1st
  host2: whatever you want 2nd

This gives the same result
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e @target_hosts_dict.yml



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: target_hosts | d([]) | type_debug

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ switch }}"
      vars:
        target: "{{ target_hosts | d([]) }}"
        type: "{{ target | type_debug }}"
        switch: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% if type == 'str' %}
          {{ target | split(',') }}
          {% elif type == 'list' %}
          {{ target }}
          {% elif type == 'dict' %}
          {{ target.keys() }}
          {% else %}
          []
          {% endif %}
          {% endfilter %}


